# VHDL Syntax explanation needed

Tags: vhdl

Can somebody explain what the following line of code does?
Google search did not turn up anything useful.

```
data_count <= (others => ’0’);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sets all elements of data_count to `'0'`.

The datatype of data_count would be an array of elements that can be `'0'`, like `bit_vector`, `std_logic_vector`, `signed` or `unsigned`. If your signal data_count has four bits, this would be equivalent to writing:

```
data_count <= "0000";
```

with the advantage that you don't have to count the bits.

You can also set certain elements to '1' and then the rest to '0':

```
data_count <= (1 => '1', 3 => '1', others=>'0');
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement sets all the elements to`'0'` 
You can also use this statement as `others => '1'` this will set elements to `'1'`

suppose data_count is a std_logic_vector( 6 downto 0 ) , 
then the data_ count will be assigned as `data_count <= "0000000"`

suppose you write `data_count <= (5 => '1' , others => ’0’);`

and data_count suppose is a std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0 ) , this means 6th bit is 1 and rest are 0 ie

`data_count <= "00100000" ;`